# How to report Zenity bugs

Tags: zenity

I've been running an app that never terminates. It does have progress to report and I am using the zenity progress dialog to do so. After a period of several hours zenity has eaten most (and eventually all) of the available memory and swap space. I want to report this but can't find where. (The problem may actually be in GTK which zenity uses).

My current workaround is to periodically close the dialog and reopen it. This is causing the dialog to reappear in the center of the screen. Annoying but better than the alternative.

The actual question is where to report this problem. If anyone has a better workaround, that would be nice.

Answer (score 2):

The bugs can be reported to gnome.org at

https://bugzilla.gnome.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=zenity